# Java code in Android to create imageView

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. 
I have a button on a Fragment and I need to write a java code inside the onClick listener of my button such that when I press the button on UI, an imageView automatically and programmatically is created on the page. The next time I press the button, another image view is created just near the previous one and etc. How to create multiple different objects of that imageView? 
Moreover, I need those created imageViews to be shown next time I run the app. 
How to solve this scenario, it seems as if the xml code or even java code should be kept somewhere else just like when you drag and drop that component.
Any idea, solutions, code examples and links are appreciated.
(Following is just a sample code to create 1 imageView but this is not what I am looking for.)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // Initialize a new ImageView widget
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
            // Set an image for ImageView
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cafe);
            // Create layout parameters for ImageView
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // Add rule to layout parameters
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button9);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            // Finally, add the ImageView to layout
            r1.addView(iv, lp);


            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.breakfast);
        }
```

Comment: I suggest that you use a RecyclerView. You also need some kind of permanent storage in order to persist the images on each run of the app. You can do this with a flat file or a database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The image itself is not the problem. I get them from remote server.
The problem is the imageView. When the app runs for the first time there is no imageView component. But gradually the user customize it. Whenever the user push the button, an imageView component is created then she can select a picture.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the information from your previous comment. In particular, it can be helpful for anyone trying to answer your question to know where the images come from. Although my wording in my previous comment was a little bit off, the basic concept still applies. You need some permanent storage to specify what images will be loaded into image views. There are many possible ways to do this.

Comment: I also suggest that you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].